# Refused to display in a frame because it set X-Frame-Options to deny (Microsoft Graph API)

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365api

We are trying to integrate Office 365 Email in Twilio Flex. I'm setting the iframe URL to webLink from Microsoft Graph API ("https://outlook.office365.com/owa/?ItemID={MESSAGE_ID}&exvsurl=1&viewmodel=ReadMessageItem"). I'm able to open the email on the browser, but when set to iFrame I get an error as **Refused to display in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'.** How to display office 365 email in an iFrame.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to say this, but MS still doesn't allow OWA displayed in iFrame for security reasons.

Alternative implementation - CMS.

Comment: HI Stefan,

What is CMS? Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Integrate MS Graph API into your system.